# RTL and LTR icon positioning

Tags: css

I have attached the below image URL , for that I have used below code,but I am not able to align icon right. Can anyone please help me out to revert the image or particular icon position, right to left.

```
.icon-alignleft:before {
    content: "\e00a";
}
```

Thank you

[image]

Comment: please share more content

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to flip the container holding the icon horizontally using [`transform`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp).

```
.icon-alignleft {
   -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
   -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
   -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
   -ms-transform: scaleX(-1);
   transform: scaleX(-1);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you

(flip image/icon)

```
.icon-alignleft:before {
    content: "\e00a";
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.rtl-icon {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
     -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
      -ms-transform: scaleX(-1);
       -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
          transform: scaleX(-1);
}
```

Comment: Consider adding some explanation to your answer